# Conhost error 0xc0000005 causes application launch failed

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, windows-7, crash

I have 2 .bat files:

A.bat:

```
start myprogram.exe
start B.bat
```

B.bat

```
<log current time to Windows Event Viewer for debugging>
javaw (or java) myjava
```

`A.bat` is executed on Windows 7 (32 bit) start up which is subject to stress test (the machine is restarted every 10 minutes). The restart action is done by `myjava`. At the beginning of `myjava` I log current time into a file for debugging purpose.

The problem is, sometimes (after 50-100 restarts) `myjava` is not executed but B.bat is executed (I see the first log in Event Viewer but not the second log from `myjava`). This also happens if `myjava` is replaced by simple C++ program (so it's not JVM issue).

The only common thing is a conhost 0xc0000005 error log, right after my first log in Event Viewer:

```
Fauilting application name: conhost.exe, version: 6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb02e5
Fauilting module name: conhost.exe, version: 6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb02e5
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00001632
Faulting process id: 0xdb0
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfb84ffc3da56f
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\conhost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\conhost.exe
Report Id: 3be0cf06-2443-11e4-bf16-00e02711104e
```

There is possibility that this is the fault of `myprogram.exe` but I have no visibility on what it does. This also does NOT occur in Windows XP.

Comment: Crashing conhost.exe is a pretty nasty machine stability issue.  There are no breadcrumbs in your question, try another machine.

Comment: It also happen in another machine with different hardwares (all run Windows 7)

Comment: Take a look on Microsoft support article [An application that calls the ReadConsoleOutputCharacter function closes unexpectedly or data becomes corrupted when the application runs in Windows 7 or in Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977648).

Comment: capture a dmp of conhost.exe with procdump (http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-9-ProcDump) and analyze it with Windbg (**!analyze -v**). Post the output here.